# math help please

Tags: vectors

A plane flies 1.4 hours at 120 mph on a bearing of 10degrees. It then turns and flies 7.9 hours at the same speed on a bearing of 100degrees. How far is the plane from its starting​ point?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: I would start by sketching the path of the plane.

Comment: Are the speed and bearing relative to the air or to the ground?

Comment: With the ~ 1500 km distance in the second leg, would you consider the curvature of the Earth? (Unless that "mph" is meters per hour.)